# How can I inform the reusable parent component about an event happened inside the ng content in Angular?

Tags: angular

I want to implement a reusable dropdown component in Angular that gets its dropdown content in the ng-content so that I can use it as a "choose from list", as a "choose from tree", etc. (That is in short, I want to extract the selection label that opens and closes the dropdown on click.)

dropdown.component.ts

```
<!-- code for the selection label -->
<div *ngIf="open">
    <ng-content />
</div>
```

One potential use:

```
<my-dropdown [selection]="selection">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let option of options" (click)="select(option)">
            {{option.label}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</my-dropdown>
```

Another potential use:

```
<my-dropdown [selection]="selection">
    <!-- code for a tree from which the user can select -->
</my-dropdown>
```

The problem I have is to inform the dropdown component about a selection (such that the dropdown component can save the selection and close the menu). Because the selection happens in the ng-content, I cannot emit some value to the parent component, something like

dropdown.component.ts (in my dreams)

```
<!-- code for the selection label -->
<div *ngIf="open">
    <ng-content (selectEvent)="saveAndCloseMenu($event)"/>
</div>
```

*would be* what I need.

A shared service also doesn't seem like a good idea since services are singletons and there could be more dropdowns at once.

What is a good, clean solution for this problem?

Comment: Is your content always supposed to be a ul? What else could your content be? Asking if it would make sense for your component to accept ng-content or if your my-dropdown component should accept configuration (e.g. `items`) and be in charge of its own internal markup (which changes the scope of this problem)

Comment: Adding on from the above, if you envision it taking a selection input, it really feels like it should take a list of items (that could be resolved to a tree).

Comment: @AdamJenkins Currently, the two possibilities are a "select from list" (with an ul, li, etc.) and a "select from tree" (where the content is a recursive custom component that builds a tree view that can be expanded, collapsed, etc.). Actually the base problem is, I have duplicated code for the selection label that I want to extract.

Comment: I don’t think you should extract the duplicated code into a component - it sounds like you have two different components. And you’d be coupling them with an abstraction just for the purpose of the label. Don’t over-DRY your code. But it’d be neat to see a stackblitz of these components to get a better idea of what they look like and what you’re trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code like this and pass the selected option as input to my-dropdown and handle it in ngOnChanges:

app.component.html

```
<my-dropdown [selection]="selection" [selectOption]="selectOption">
 <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let option of options" (click)="select(option)">
      {{option.label}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</my-dropdown>
```

app.component.ts

```
 selectOption;
    select(event:any) : void {
    this.selectOption = event;

    }
```

my-dropdown.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './my-dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-dropdown.component.scss']
})
export class MyDropdownComponent implements OnChanges {
  open = true;
  @Input() selection: any;
  @Input() selectOption: any;

  constructor() {
  }


  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes && changes['selectOption'] && 
     !changes['selectOption'].firstChange) {
      alert(this.selectOption.label)
    }
  }

}
```

my-dropdown.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="open">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```